# Where has the 'Set to map canvas Extent' on QGIS Version gone?

Tags: qgis, qgsmapcanvas

I am using QGIS Version 3.10.0 . When using Map Composer I can not find the 'Set to map canvas Extent button'. When clicking on the extent tab The image below shows all the options I have.

[image]

Does anyone know why it is not there anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location for these options has been moved to the top of item properties of your map. See:

[image]